# Change items in combobox depending on conditions

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a school project where the user inputs their flight destination and time

Im using comboboxes to select the destination

is there anyway, when the user inputs a certain destination it will change the options in the following combobox

such as if "Sydney" is selected the only times available when the user chooses the time will be: 
14:00
18:00

Thanks

Comment: There is a way. I think you need to be way more specific. Are you loading info from a database? How do you know which times are approved for which flights? Is it all hard coded in arrays? Lists? Etc... Much more information is needed for a legitimate response.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's very important to look here [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.